# The apk file compiled by buildozer keeps crashing

Tags: android, python-3.x, apk, buildozer

I have managed to compile py files to apk using buildldozer. My apk app only shows "hello wordl" message, but when I try to run the app to android 9 virtual, the apk app crashes "App Keeps Stopping". Maybe here, some people have experience about my problem to solve my problem. Thanks

[App Keeps Stopping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/iT3D8.png)

I've tried several solutions from the internet like clearing app cache, permissions and other recommended solutions.

Comment: Are you using logcat? Show me the logs, maybe it has a python traceback

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.